# How will I know the mouse position when mouse is clicked in QgraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a mouseReleaseEvent in my **QGraphicsView** class. By the way, I am using mouseReleaseEvent since if I used the mousePressEvent nothing will happen, no ellipse will be added to the the scene. I don't know how I can find the exact position of the mouse so that the I can use it as the position for my ellipse.Currenlty mo code can addEllipse but the position is not the same in the mouse, same in the picture here:

[image: here]

Update Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJFLL.png)
self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)

```
 def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        obj = self._scene.addEllipse(self._size/2, self._size/2, 10, 10,Qt.red) 
        obj.setPos(x,y)
        self.objects.append(obj)
        #self.posprev =pos
```

I tried using **obj.ScenePos()** to get the postion but it still does not work.

Comment: You're already getting the mouse position, what is the problem? Also, if you didn't get it in the `mousePressEvent` then it's because you added/did something that prevents the view to get the event.

Comment: @musicamante if I click the scene, the ellipse position should be the same to my mouse position but what happen is they have different position like in the picture above. Is there away I can add the ellipse same to the mouse position?

Comment: There is, but the way to do it depends on various aspects. It's usually easier to do that by overriding the `mousePressEvent` of the scene instead of that of the view, but, in any case, you must consider two aspects: the graphics view framework uses [three corrdinate systems](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system), so if you're implementing `mousePressEvent` on the view, you must map the position to the scene. Then you have to consider that if the view has no elements, you should set the sceneRect, otherwise the view will translate it when the scene changes.

Comment: Thank you. I am almost near to my goal. I followed your suggestion by adding **setSceneRect** which I set the dimension similar to my QGraphicsView's dimension. Then, I added **mapToScene** on my mouseReleaseEvent. The result is if I use addLine using the previous and present position of the mouse, it works. It has the same position as to where I clicked the mouse. However, if I used the addEllipse, it did not work. There is a small difference between the position of the mouse and the position of the ellipse. Do you know the reason for it? I added **update image**  above to show what I mean.